# Why doesnot absolute_file_name work

Tags: gnu-prolog

The following code works in swi-prolog:

```
:- asserta(user:file_search_path(money, '/media/D/db')).
dataFile(F) :-
absolute_file_name(money('test.dat'), F, []).
```

It seems there is no module in gprolog. How can i make it work under gprolog ?

Sincerely!

Answer (score 0):

You do not give enough details but I deduce the problem is the operator '**:-**' Try with '**initialization/1**'

```
$ cat > file.pl

initialization(asserta(user:file_search_path(money, '/media/D/db'))).
dataFile(F) :- absolute_file_name(money('test.dat'), F, []).
^d

$ gprolog --init-goal "['file.pl']"
compiling /Users/user/file.pl for byte code...
/Users/user/file.pl compiled, 2 lines read - 763 bytes written, 8 ms
GNU Prolog 1.4.1
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2012 Daniel Diaz
| ?-
```

Hope this work…

Comment: consult is OK but file_search_path(money,X).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,file_search_path/2),top_level/0)
| ?- dataFile(X).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,absolute_file_name/3),dataFile/1)

Comment: file_search_path is not an ISO directive and it is not implemented by [gnuprolog](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.pdf). You have to look for an alternative or implement your own directive (check the file processing and operating system interface)